How to get a binding to an `@ObservableObject` property from `UIHostingConfiguration`
UIHostingConfiguration enables using SwiftUI views as collection view and table view cells. I have a NSManagedObject I'd like to read/write from my cells, but my issue is that I haven'g found any good way to get a working binding to the properties.
I tried storing the object as a property of my UIKit view controller (which I suppose is probably not ok in the first place, but was worth trying)
@ObservedObject var foo = MyCoreDataEntity()

And then getting a binding to it
UIHostingConfiguration {
    MyView(content: $foo.bar)
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var content: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Text(content)
           SomeEditorView($content)
        }
    }
}

But it seems observation is broken in this case: the updates to the property seem to be transmitted to the  NSManagedObject, but the Text SwiftUI view doesn't react to the changes, as if it hadn't been "connected" to the changes.
The only approach I see would be to directly store the whole @ObservedObject in MyView, but that's not very clean as it makes the view less reusable.
Any ideas?

Instead of putting the @ObservedObject in MyView, how about creating an additional view that wraps MyView? You can put the @ObservedObject in the wrapper view.

@Sweeper Thanks! Hadn't thought of this specifically. I think it does improve the reusability as it still enables defining a SwiftUI view that doesn't have to be linked to the observed object type and then wrap it as you described, if there is no better approach I will probably do this.
